In MFC/C++, how do I center a tool window in its parent dialog?
In MFC/C++,I have a dialog-based project. The modal MainDialog contains a member ToolDlg, a modeless dialog. I want ToolDlg to appear centered in MainDialog. My code doesn't do this; ToolDlg isn't centered.
The code I'm using is
In MainDialog.h:
ToolDlg toolDlg;
In MainDialog.cpp:
    if(!toolDlg.m_hWnd)
    {
        toolDlg.parentDlg = this; // toolDlg uses some functions defined in the parent
        toolDlg.Create(IDD_ToolDlg, this);

        // Center toolDlg in MainDailog's window
        CRect r0, r1;
        GetWindowRect(&r0);
        toolDlg.GetWindowRect(&r1); ScreenToClient(&r1);
        r1.MoveToXY((r0.Width() - r1.Width()) / 2, (r0.Height() - r1.Height()) / 2);
        toolDlg.MoveWindow(r1);
    }
    toolDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

It is possible the 150% scaling is affecting this, but multiplying the distances by 1.5 also doesn't produce the desired result.
What am I doing wrong?
Windows 11, VS2022, C++20
Monitor is 3840 x 2160, scaled 150%

Can’t you use CentrrWindow()?  Should center in its parent.

@Andrew Truckle: CenterWindow( ) works. I am still wondering, however, why my code does not.

This should not even be needed. By default, a popup window opens centered on its parent. Check whether you have the WS_CHILD style on your popup window.
